# Crystal Reports Viewer Toolbar Directory keeps Changing

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

[image]I'm using the Crystal Reports Viewer in my ASP.net web pages, and the toolbar is NOT working.  I can get it to work for a month or so by changing the number shown in the picture attached...however this is becoming an issue having to keep changing my directory over and over every time this happens.  Where is this number coming from and how can I just hard code the path to this directory for the Crystal Reports Viewer?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question - it prompted me to finally pull my finger out and deploy the Service Pack to a server here.. it's only been sat on my to-do list since April last year! =)

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by updates to the .NET Framework being installed which cause the ASP.NET version to change (which is the part of the URL you can see changing). Certain versions of Crystal Reports always take the current ASP.NET version as the one to slot into the URL, rather than sticking with the original version number.

At least with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio, this was fixed in [Service Pack 16](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/SAP+Crystal+Reports%2C+developer+version+for+Microsoft+Visual+Studio+-+Service+Pack+16+-+Fixed+Issues):

> Incident 878969
>
> > Framework 4.6 causes CR for VS to create a unique folder path to the Crystalreportsviewer13 folder in IIS and IISExpress

Depending on what product you're using, you'll need to go through the SAP site (sorry!) and find the latest service pack. The SAP KB article link for this issue is [here](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/0002250097) and states that the issue has been resolved for:

- Crystal Reports for Visual Studio SP20
- Crystal Reports for Visual Studio SP21
- BOE 4.0 - no fix available due to end of patch cycle
- BOE 4.1 SP 10 or higher
- BOE 4.2 SP 4 or higher
- Any release after April 2017.